# WriteAsync with DataReader how to stop reading

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1

I have to upload a mp4 (Windows Phone 8.1 App C#) to a ftp and it works actually with the following code... but even after days of try'n'error I just don't know how write a condition for the end of the while. I can get the size of the file but don't know how to check for written bytes? Please help me

```
    using (var stream2 = await ftpClient.OpenWriteAsync(PathToSet + FileName + ".mp4"))
    {              
        using (var readStream = await videofile.OpenReadAsync())
        {
            IBuffer buffer = await FileIO.ReadBufferAsync(videofile);
            DataReader reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(buffer);
            byte[] fileContent = new byte[reader.UnconsumedBufferLength];                    

            //int FileSize = Convert.ToInt32(reader.UnconsumedBufferLength);

            while (true)
            {
                fileContent = new byte[reader.UnconsumedBufferLength];
                reader.ReadBytes(fileContent);

                await stream2.WriteAsync(fileContent.AsBuffer());

                if(???) break;
            }

            await stream2.FlushAsync();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Check whether [`UnconsumedBufferLength`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.storage.streams.datareader.unconsumedbufferlength.aspx) is zero.

Comment: Hi SLaks, thank you very much for you answer but if check it `if (reader.UnconsumedBufferLength <= 0) break;` after the first run of the while reader.UnconsumeBufferLenght is 0 and my file has only 5808 Bytes